# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory calling a WS

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I want to test a XML Web Services (JAX-WS) deployed on a JBoss 7 and created with maven on an Eclipse so I created a Junit test to do so.
Here my Junit test

```
public class IberiaWSTest {

     @Test
      public void testListPerson() throws Exception {

         IberiaWSBindingStub stub = new IberiaWSBindingStub(new URL("http://iberia.test.buildizz.com/IberiaWSPort"),null);

     }
}
```

and this is the class

```
public class IberiaWSBindingStub extends org.apache.axis.client.Stub implements IberiaWS_PortType {

    private java.util.Vector cachedSerClasses = new java.util.Vector();
    private java.util.Vector cachedSerQNames = new java.util.Vector();
    private java.util.Vector cachedSerFactories = new java.util.Vector();
    private java.util.Vector cachedDeserFactories = new java.util.Vector();

    static org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc [] _operations;

    static {
        _operations = new org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc[7];
        _initOperationDesc1();
    }
..

}
```

and

```
public interface IberiaWS_PortType extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public int createPerson(IberiaPerson arg0) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public .String arg0) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.String arg0) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public boolean isConnected() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.s java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public boolean login(java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
    public int updatePerson(com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.i.RemoteException;
}
```

Even there is no reference anywhere to logggin, I got this error when running the Junit test

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
    at org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc.<clinit>(OperationDesc.java:65)
    at com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.client.IberiaWSBindingStub._initOperationDesc1(IberiaWSBindingStub.java:27)
    at com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.client.IberiaWSBindingStub.<clinit>(IberiaWSBindingStub.java:21)
    at com.iberia.iberiafleet.webservice.IberiaWSTest.testListPerson(IberiaWSTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Do you have commons-logging on your classpath somewhere? It is a dependency of Axis apparently.

Comment: no, I don't have... I will add it